# How to hide <th> if <td> is empty in my list when generating PDF using power Automate

Tags: html, pdf, automation

I have a flow that generates a pdf from my Microsoft list id. Is it possible in the compose part of the flow to exclude a column that has no data? I've seem many answers but i cannot figure where to put the codes that are mentioned as im quite new to this.

my data is in a simple table below as an example.

Full power Automate flow

[image]

Part of the flow

[image]

If the Supplier value is blank in my SharePoint list how do I get it to exclude this so it doesn't pull through to the final PDF as not every field will be used every time and having loads of empty tables doesn't really look good. please note. multiple fields could be blank im just using the supplier as an example of how you could show me what to do. if the table data is empty or no data exclude the the table header as well as currently if the field is blank the table header remains but with a collapsible table data field. any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

I have not tried anything yet as I don't know what to do.